# A named connection string was used, but the name was not found in the application's configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I am developing an ASP.NET Core 3.0 Web API Application with EF CORE Database-First approach, however I am facing a strange error while accessing the database context from API Controller.

Error Message:

> A named connection string was used, but the name 'GPMS' was not found
> in the application's configuration. Note that named connection strings
> are only supported when using 'IConfiguration' and a service provider,
> such as in a typical ASP.NET Core application. See
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=850912 for more information

My Connection string in appsettings.json file:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "GPMS": "Data Source=SERVER_IP;Initial Catalog=GPMS;User Id=DB_USER;Password=DB_PASSWORD"
  }
```

I have also tried connection string in this way:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
        "GPMS": "Server=SERVER_IP;Database=GPMS;User Id=DB_USER;Password=DB_PASSWORD"
      }
```

I have registered it in IService in Startup.cs as below:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
    services.AddControllers();    
    services.AddDbContext<GPMSContext>(options =>
             options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("GPMS")));
 }
```

But no luck in this. Can anyone help me to rectify the issue?

Comment: looks like the configuration is not loaded, what is your environment? does the corresponding settings file for it exist? Note that for environment of "Development", both the `appsettings.json` and `appsettings.Development.json` are loaded with the later overwriting the former.

Comment: Check to make sure that the setting file is being copied to output directory when project is compiled and run.

Comment: @KingKing i m using development environment and  both appsettings.json and appsettings.Development.json are updated with same connection string. also both files are being copied to output directory, but its still generating same error message

Comment: Try this: options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:GPMS"])

Comment: @AribYousuf issue resolved by using IConfiguration from my Startup.cs class. I have used its reference in my DBContext class to access the connection string

Comment: What was the final solution to this? I am encountering the same problem and am brand new to EF Core development.

Comment: @Jake i have resolved this issue by using IConfiguration object as a global reference and then get connection string from IConfiguration in options setting

Comment: Usman, I also fixed the problem like you did, created a global reference.  I wish there was a better way though.  Maybe there is and it's beyond my understanding.